# Why v-model is not working on a specific field only?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a form with the following fields that are into play in this module. All the variables are updated in real-time using `v-model` from the list given below, except the `net_rate`.

- Quantity
- Rate
- Discount
- Net Rate

I am getting product information from the API and I have created an `selectedItem: {}` object in my `data`. I can bind all these fields with my data object using `v-model` except the `net_rate`.

I don't know what's the issue here as I am trying to solve this problem since last 4 days. But here is all the information and code you might need to help me solve the issue.

**Data:**

```
data () {
    return {
        selectedItem: {},
    }
},
```

**Markup with v-model Binding**

```
<div class="inline-form-group  col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-right">
    <label for="quantity" style="color:teal;font-size:14px;">Qty.</label>
    <input type="text" ref="quantity" @input="setAmount()" @keydown.enter="$refs.rate.focus()" v-model="selectedItem.quantity" class="form-control text-right" />
</div>
<div class="inline-form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-right">
    <label for="cost" style="color:teal;font-size:14px;">Cost</label>
    <input type="text" ref="cost" disabled v-model="selectedItem.cost" class="form-control text-right" />
</div>
<div class="inline-form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-right">
    <label for="rate" style="color:teal;font-size:14px;">Rate</label>
    <input type="text" ref="rate" @keydown.enter="$refs.discount_perc.focus()" @input="setAmount()" v-model="selectedItem.price" class="form-control text-right" />
</div>
<div class="inline-form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-right">
    <label for="discount_perc" style="color:teal;font-size:14px;">Dis %</label>
    <input type="text" ref="discount_perc" @keydown.enter="$refs.net_rate.focus()" @input="setAmount()" v-model="selectedItem.discount_perc" class="form-control text-right" />
</div>
<div class="inline-form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-right">
    <label for="net_rate" style="color:teal;font-size:14px;">Net Rate</label>
    <input type="text" ref="net_rate" @input="setAmount()" v-model="selectedItem.net_rate" class="form-control text-right" />
</div>
```

You can ignore the `cost` here because it is not used anywhere. It's pre-defined and is not changed in the module.

Please note that all the other variables like `rate`, `discount_perc`, `quantity` are successfully bound and are working. But only the `net_rate` field is not working. Here are the functions that are used in this calculation.

**Functions:**

```
setAmount: function () {
    if(this.selectedItem.net_rate !== this.selectedItem.price){
        var discount_percAmount = this.selectedItem.discount_perc?(this.selectedItem.discount_perc*this.selectedItem.price)/100:0;
        this.selectedItem.net_rate = this.selectedItem.price-discount_percAmount;
    }

    if(this.selectedItem.size_breadth > 0 && this.selectedItem.size_length > 0){
        this.selectedItem.item_amt = this.selectedItem.net_rate*this.selectedItem.quantity*this.selectedItem.size_breadth*this.selectedItem.size_length;
    } else {
        this.selectedItem.item_amt = this.selectedItem.net_rate*this.selectedItem.quantity;
    }
},
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am totally frustrated because of this error.

Comment: On objects, Vue cannot detect changes of properties. It can only detect if the reference of the object itself changes. This is due to the nature of Javascript. Instead of `obj.myProp = 10;` you need to do `Vue.set(obj, 'myProp', 10);`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: @connexo But it detects and updates other fields inside the same object.

Comment: @connexo and what should be the perfect solution for this proble,?

Comment: You can give it an initial value in the data object, so Vue knows about it. `selectedItem: { net_rate: 0, }`. Currently Vue is not aware of the property, follow the link that @connexo posted and it will explain that perfectly.

Comment: I tried using `Vue.set` and luckily, I am out of this irresponsive error. But I got another one now. I can't update anything in that field because it resets back to whatever value it had before. For example, if the initial value in the field is '95' and I try to update it to '950', It resets back to '95'.

Comment: Nevermind, It looks like some issue with conditions. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @connexo in the comment,

On objects, [Vue cannot detect changes of properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). It can only detect if the reference of the object itself changes. This is due to the nature of Javascript. Instead of `obj.myProp = 10;` you need to do `Vue.set(obj, 'myProp', 10);`

You will need to do:

```
setAmount: function () {
    if(this.selectedItem.net_rate !== this.selectedItem.price){
        var discount_percAmount = this.selectedItem.discount_perc?(this.selectedItem.discount_perc*this.selectedItem.price)/100:0;
        Vue.set(this.selectedItem, 'net_rate', this.selectedItem.price-discount_percAmount);
    }

    if(this.selectedItem.size_breadth > 0 && this.selectedItem.size_length > 0){
        Vue.set(this.selectedItem, 'item_amt', this.selectedItem.net_rate*this.selectedItem.quantity*this.selectedItem.size_breadth*this.selectedItem.size_length);
    } else {
        Vue.set(this.selectedItem, 'item_amt', this.selectedItem.net_rate*this.selectedItem.quantity);
    }
},
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question. The issue is, I can't get the value entered by user in the `net_rate` field. I can perform calculation if I get value, but the issue is I am unable to get value from `net_rate` field.

Answer (score 0):

As [connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo) has said perfectly in his comment.

Vue is currently unaware that this property exists as explained below.

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive. For example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  }
})
// `vm.a` is now reactive

vm.b = 2
// `vm.b` is NOT reactive
```

We need to tell Vue that this value exists and we want it to be reactive, so let's modify that in your data object.

```
data () {
    return {
        selectedItem: {
          quantity: 0,
          cost: 0,
          price: 0,
          discount_perc: 0,
          net_rate: 0,
        },
    }
},
```